# xaHow to break running nested loop from the outside

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot give recommendation about combine fodder, the problem is, if the input number is too big, it will write out like 20-30 lines

I tried `return;` but it didn't work, `process.exit()` it will stop the bot completely and i'll have to turn it on manually

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, 
   m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 10000 });
            message.channel.send("Do you have Expboost? (y/n)")
            message.channel.send("Type `stop` to stop the recommandation")
            collector.on('collect', message => {
                if (message.content == "y") {
                    calculateFodder(expNeed, rarity, 1.1, message);   \\nested loop
                } else if (message.content == "n") {
                    calculateFodder(expNeed, rarity, 1, message);   \\nested loop
                } else if (message.content == "stop")
                    process.exit()
            })
```

my `calculateFodder` function is something like this, the real one just have 1-2 more loop

```
function calculateFodder(totalExp, message) {
            for (var i=0; i<totalExp/8000; i++ ){
                        for (var j=0; j<totalExp/10000; j++){
                                    message.channel.send("you need " + i +"and" + j);
                        }
            }
}
```

Comment: Where's the loop?  Or what causes a loop?  Also, where's the input number and how does it write out 20-30 lines.  I think maybe we need to see more of the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 the calculateFodder function is the loop, i added an example of it, the expNeed is the input number

Comment: Is it like you don't wan't to write out any line when input number is too big (please define limit) or do you want to write out some lines and then break the loop?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia I want it write out some lines and stop whenever user send `stop`, can it possible? I know i can set a limit like break when 10th lines has been written